# How does snapchat achieve a drop down menu for their settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am having trouble understanding how to go about creating a swipe down gesture to bring down an overlay that is another screen with its own objects and Images and then be able to swipe back to the original screen.

I currently have a scroll view with 3 screens. A | B | C  and I am trying to add an upward gesture to bring up notes and down gesture to bring down a settings screen (like snapchat's when you click on the ghost or swipe the ghost down) with my own Image, from B. So ideally like this:

```
    D

A | B | C

    E
```

So how could I create D & E to be swipe up and down views that are triggered by gestures... Any one have any ideas how to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can create this by two ways

1) create a view (code/nib) and set it's `autolayout` constraint to be at the top (outside of your `scrollView` frame) once you press a button or recognise a swipe down gesture you change the constraints constant value to the `scrollView's` height (don't forget to call `layoutIfNeeded` after the change).

2) use a container view (i recommend using nib for that), add all the objects and buttons you wish to the container view. In the `scrollView` just use the container as any other view to animate it's location.

IMPORTANT: ether way don't set the view/`containerView` to be a subView of the `scrollView.contentView` you need to add it to the `scrollView's` superView in order for it to stay in it's place

**EDIT**

in viewDidLoad or something

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userSwipedDown:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

selector implementation

```
- (void)userSwipedDown:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  // if this method has been called then the user has swiped down
  // show the view
}
```

Comment: I realized asking such open ended, please help, questions are nonsense so: 1. Do I make the code/nib files just like I did for the three View controllers that scroll? If so, how do I connect my button object from the old screen to the new view I created that drops down?

Comment: you can use Delegation or KVO

Comment: I have been using delegation, but my issue is this, in my storyboard, I have a start screen that contains a button that displays, when presses, a UI scrollview containing 3 .xib files ( for A, B, and C). So I can not link a button in A to the next controller that would contain the dropdown in my storyboard. Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I think i misunderstood you. from your Q i understood that you have a scrollView with contentView the size of 3 views and you want to implement another 2 views one that comes from the top and one that comes from the bottom. Right?

Comment: I do have  a scrollview with the size of three views but that appears after a button is pressed in the main app screen. So to do this, I have my story board containing two containers, one for the start menu and one with a UI Scroll view. The UI Scroll view is linked to three .xib files through a separate .swift file that is not the viewcontroller.swift. I want to create a fourth .xib file, "Settings", and have it drop down from A.xib which is the center screen of the  UIScrollView. Let me know if that makes more sense. Thanks again

Comment: so what does the button have to do with the swipe down/up menu?

Comment: If you see snapchat's swipe down, it has a button (the ghost) and you can either tap him to drop the menu, or drag him down to bring down the menu. I am trying to achieve the same thing with my own image. Should I not use a button?

Comment: you should use a button, but the button needs to be in view B

Comment: Just got the drop down to work with a button and using a hidden view that triggers on or off. How do you do this same hide/unhide but with gestures?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a simple feature within my app and I just figured it out. I have A | B | (haven't got onto C yet) in a `scrollview` as `child view controllers`. Within B I have a `scrollview` as the `subview`. For the original parent `scrollview`, I have `contentSize` stretched out horizontally. Within B's subview `scrollview`, I have the `contentsize` stretched out vertically.

I know you are looking for swift code, but if you know your obj-c, I guess implementing in swift would be pretty straight forward. I am, at the time of posting this answer, unfamiliar with Swift but I do plan on learning it sometime soon.